# Can this deleted question be undeleted and reopened?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, deleted-questions, closed-questions

The question [What if you cannot pay the damages in a civil law suit?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/80677/what-if-you-cannot-pay-the-fine-in-a-civil-law-suit) was closed as a duplicate – incorrectly, in my view. I was in the process of writing a comment explaining my view, following which I intended to vote to reopen, when the post author deleted the question.

I think this was incorrectly closed as a duplicate because the linked question dealt with a **refusal** to comply with a court order, while the current question deals with an **inability to pay** a damage award – which is a very different thing, and does not normally lead to a contempt citation.

I would like to have the deleted question undeleted and reopened so that answers can be posted. Is that possible?

Comment: It says it was closed as duplicate but also deleted by the post author at about the aame time. Not sure if that latter action makes a difference to it being reopened..?

Comment: @Rick The deletion came after, although not very long after, the closure. I was responding to the closure when the deletion occurred. I have voted to undelete.

Comment: Yes but, notwithstanding the VTC as a duplicate, it makes me wonder what the policy is for restoring a post that was specifically deleted by the author and therefore seemingly against their wishes for it remain open.  Maybe @DaleM could shed some light..?

Comment: @Rick Yes.  Since all posts are licecnes under the CC-BY-SA, the author has no **legal** right to insist on deletion, but that doesn't mean that our policy call for, undeletion.

Comment: Looks like the post has since been undeleted and reopened (by the community + mods).